# How to create a page in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have below question on page creation, i received nothing after the break. Please help.

```
        private void ItemAction(DashboardMultipleTileItemData item)
    {
        switch (item.Title)

        {
            case "Contacts":
                new NavigationPage(new TabControlAndroidSamplePage());
                break;
            case "Documents":
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new EmployeePerformanceDashboardPage());
                break;
                //case "Enquiry":
                //  Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new WebSitePage()));
                //  break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi , about `case "Contacts"`, what you want to do , you can deatil in question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution will be:-

```
private void ItemAction(DashboardMultipleTileItemData item)
    {
        switch (item.Title)

        {
            case "Contacts":
                Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new TabControlAndroidSamplePage());
                break;
            case "Documents":
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new EmployeePerformanceDashboardPage());
                break;
                //case "Enquiry":
                //  Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new WebSitePage()));
                //  break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The page navigate success. but the page cannot navigate back to the previous screen, the 'back' button not function ?

Comment: To have the back button function you will have to use NavigationPage. Same as case Contacts.